# Strange errors when using math environments

Tags: errors

When working with the document below I am always getting some strange errors 
like messages like

"Bad math environment delimeter.$$["

when using a math environment. The full list can be seen below. Could you please tell me what to do to fix this?

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}



\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{#1}}
\makeatother


\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}



\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\closed}{[}{]} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\oc}{\left]}{\right[} 

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\biggabs}{\bigg\lvert}{\bigg\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}


\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}{Definition}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}  

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lemma}{Lemma}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}  

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{corollary}{Corollary}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Beweis}


\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}
\newtheorem{reminder}{Reminder}


\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Sheet 6}}
\date{}

\maketitle


\begin{enumerate}

    \setcounter{enumi}{26}

    \item 

    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
                    \item           
                    \item   
        \end{enumerate} 

    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
                    \item 

                        $$\[
                        \begin{bmatrix}[ccccc|c]
                        x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & \cdots & x_{1n} & a_{1,n+1} \\
                        x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & \cdots & x_{2n} & a_{2,n+1} \\
                        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots    \\
                        x_{d1} & x_{d2} & x_{d3} & \cdots & x_{dn} & a_{d,n+1}
                        \end{bmatrix}
                        \]$$

        \end{enumerate}       

    \item 
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
                        \item           
                        \item   
            \end{enumerate} 




\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

```
Bad math environment delimiter. $$\[
Missing \endgroup inserted. \]
\begin{enumerate} on input line 98 ended by \end{equation*}. \]
Missing $ inserted.
Missing } inserted.
Display math should end with $$.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \begin
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
You can't use `\relax' after \the. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Missing number, treated as zero. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
Undefined control sequence. \end{enumerate}
You can't use `\relax' after \the. \end{enumerate}
\begin{document} ended by \end{enumerate}. \end{enumerate}
Extra \endgroup. \end{enumerate}
inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
\fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is useless
No \author given.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected
```

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: Don't use `$$\[ \]$$`. Use directly `\[ \]`. `$$ $$` is a plain TeX construct.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks a lot. That fixed it.

Comment: B.t.w. what's `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\biggabs}{\bigg\lvert}{\bigg\rvert}` for? You obtain the same result with `\abs[\bigg]{...}`

Comment: Ah, did not know that. Thanks for pointing that out.